# Umbraco: Output contents of SVG file from media library

Tags: asp.net, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I have an SVG uploaded through the media library.
I want to be able to style the paths in the SVG using CSS, so rather than displaying it in an image tag, I need to output the XML within the file to the template.

Any ideas?

Umbraco 7.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution that works for me, but it may be messy

```
@Html.Raw(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(Umbraco.TypedMedia(globalSettings.GetProperty("websiteLogo").Value).Url)))
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful. I just wanted to come here to update this slightly to what worked for me (Umbraco 7.6.5): `@Html.Raw(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(Umbraco.TypedMedia(globalSettings.GetPropertyValue("websiteLogo").ToString()).Url)))`